# How does Varnish handle HTTP/2 Server Push?

Tags: varnish, http2

I have been looking at ways to improve page loads using HTTP2 specifically using server push.

We have a HAProxy => Varnish => Apache configuration.

I know varnish 5 can handle HTTP2 requests, but when the request has server push headers for further resources on a page do those resources come out of the cache or does it just get passed to apache?

My thinking is that if those server push headers don't get handled by varnish it would be to the determent of page loads rather than a net gain...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAProxy 1.8 only has HTTP/2 support at the front end and then will connect to Varnish using HTTP/1.1 - unless you are using this as a TCP loadbalancer rather than a HTTP loadbalancer? HAproxy 1.9 did add HTTP/2 in the backend (i.e. to downstream systems like Varnish in your setup). I do not believe either supports HTTP/2 Push when using it as a HTTP proxy.

Varnish similarly only supports HTTP/2 over the front end and not push AFAIK.

So basically you cannot use Push in your currently infrastructure. They will connect to Apache (which is the only piece with Push support) as a HTTP/1.1 connection and therefore it will not even attempt to Push resources unless using HTTP/2.

The easiest way to support this would be to simplify your infrastructure. I’m not sure if you have the volume that requires both HAProxy and Varnish or if you have some other reason to set this up this way? If not then you could either get rid of them totally and just use Apache. Alternatively just use HAProxy as a TCP proxy and connect to any Apache instances (either over TLS or not) using HTTP/2.

The other option is to put another instance of Apache in front of HAProxy to handle HTTP/2 and HTTP/2 Push. The back end connections can be over HTTP/1 then and signal to this new Apache to push a resource using Link headers (even over HTTP/1) and it will request the resource from downstream appropriately (which may read it from the Varnish cache if it’s set up that way). But running Apache -> HAProxy -> Varnish -> Apache definitely sounds like overkill for most sites.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the input but it doesn't really answer my question. I know I can enable http2 in haproxy and apache, what I want clarification on is which part of the stack handles the "push". Ideally the push headers would be interpreted by varnish and come out of the cache for maximum efficiency. If when you "push" those resources they don't come out of the cache I feel like it may not be worth it in regards to speed gains.

Comment: Please re-read the answer. You CAB enable HTTP/2 on haproxy and Apache but you CANNOT enable HTTP/2 Push on haproxy, therefore it will never be used, therefore your question does not matter. You can only enable Push if your edge point (haproxy) supports it - which it doesn’t. Just because something has HTTP/2 Support does not mean it supports ALL of HTTP/2. Notably Push is often not supported, and also being able to connect to downstream systems (e.g. Varnish/Apache) over HTTP/2 rather than just accepting incoming HTTP/2 connections is even less well supported (only Apache allows this AFAIK).

Comment: However assuming haproxy and/or Varnish did add Push support then the best option would be for the Edge point (haproxy if acting as a HTTP proxy, Varnish if haproxy is acting like a TCP proxy) to push the resource, and request this pushed resource via the Varnish cache.

Comment: Ah gotcha, cheers Barry, poor reading comprehension skills on my part. So regardless of whether varnish could interpret the push it wouldn't matter because it wont be a http2 connection between it and haproxy...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 Push is now supported in HAproxy 1.9 with "option http-use-htx"
It can use Varnish (and other non-TLS) as HTTP/2 backend servers with parameter "proto h2".

It can also use TLS HTTP/2 enabled backend servers with parameter "ssl verify none alpn h2"

However I'm strucling with Varnish 6.0 to allow HTTP/2 Push back to another HAproxy Frontend with "proto h2" enabled, as Varnish seems to only support HTTP/1.1 to its backend servers.
Even though varnishlog shows HTTP/2 protocol is used in the request from HAProxy.

I have tested the following and it works all the way with HTTP/2 (end-2-end).

*HTTP/2-browser -> Public-HAProxy-h2frontend -> Back-HAProxy-h2frontend-> HTTP/2-SSL-Webserver (IIS)*

The following fails after Varnish, as it only uses http/1.1 to the Back-HAProxy-h2frontend, need to be able to force varnish to keep using HTTP/2 to the backend server.

*HTTP/2-browser -> Public-HAProxy-h2frontend -> HTTP/2-Varnish -> Back-HAProxy-h2frontend-> HTTP/2-SSL-Webserver (IIS)*

Comment: You don't necessarily need to support HTTP/2 and/or HTTP/2 and PUSH all the way through. It is easiest to Push from your edge server by sending link headers. See this discussion about Apache on this: https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/154. I can't find anywhere to state that HAProxy supports Push at all so suspect you can't even do that, except by switching to TCP mode. Seems they prefer 103 to Push ( https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-1-9-has-arrived/#early-hints-http-103) which is probably not a bad call - Push is complicated to get right.